# How to compare many variables to one in r with ifelse?

Tags: r

I'm trying to compare many variables to one (i.e. flag values in columns 1 through 5 smaller than column 6). I could do an ifelse like: want=ifelse(coll1 lt coll6 |coll2 lt coll6 | coll3 lt coll6...etc. ... 1, 0) but this is too long as I have hundreds of columns. Also, many columns have NA and they are formatted as POSIXct dates. Anyone know?

Thanks!

Want:

```
df<-data.frame(col1=c("2000-01-06", "2000-01-07", "2000-01-04", "2000-01-07", NA, "2000-01-03", NA),
               col2=c("2000-01-07", "2000-01-05", NA, NA, NA, NA,NA),
               col3=c("2000-01-09", "2000-01-05", NA, NA, NA, NA, NA),
               col4=c("2000-01-10", "2000-01-05", NA, "2000-01-07", "2000-01-08", NA, NA),
               col5=c("2000-01-08", "2000-01-05", NA, NA, NA, NA, NA),
               col6=c("2000-01-06", "2000-01-07", "2000-01-05", "2000-01-06", "2000-01-08", "2000-01-09", "2000-01-08"),
               want=c(0, 1, 1, 0,0, 1, NA))


        col1       col2       col3       col4       col5       col6 want
1 2000-01-06 2000-01-07 2000-01-09 2000-01-10 2000-01-08 2000-01-06    0
2 2000-01-07 2000-01-05 2000-01-05 2000-01-05 2000-01-05 2000-01-07    1
3 2000-01-04       <NA>       <NA>       <NA>       <NA> 2000-01-05    1
4 2000-01-07       <NA>       <NA> 2000-01-07       <NA> 2000-01-06    0
5       <NA>       <NA>       <NA> 2000-01-08       <NA> 2000-01-08    0
6 2000-01-03       <NA>       <NA>       <NA>       <NA> 2000-01-09    1
7       <NA>       <NA>       <NA>       <NA>       <NA> 2000-01-08   NA
```

Comment: Please update your sample `df` to be more representative of your actual case. Perhaps provide `dput(head(your_data_here))`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can compare the 1:5 column dataset with the 6th column, use `rowSums` to create a logical vector and replace the values to `NA` where the row is all `NA`

```
i1 <- !rowSums(!is.na(df[1:5]))
df$want <- (rowSums(df[1:5] < df[,6], na.rm = TRUE) > 0) * (NA^i1)
df$want
#[1]  0  1  1  0  0  1 NA
```

---

In the updated example, the columns were `factor` class.  We can first convert to `Date` class with `as.Date`, then do the comparison by looping over the columns, get the `rowSums` as before on the logical matrix

```
df[1:6] <- lapply(df[1:6], as.Date)
df$want <- (rowSums(sapply(df[, 1:5], `<`, df[,6]), na.rm = TRUE) > 0) * (NA^i1)
df$want
#[1]  0  1  1  0  0  1 NA
```

Comment: this is a great solution but I don't think it works for POSIXct values (sorry should have clarified)

Comment: @biostatguy12  Do you want to eexclude those columns from the comparison?

Comment: no, I am comparing dates (for example I want to see if dates in col1-col5 is earlier than col 6; sorry, I thought a numeric solution would have transfered to my data)

Comment: i like this solution for its compact and can be extended to n number of variables without specifying the column names.

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you're trying to do? (Using `dplyr`)

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  as_tibble() %>% 
  mutate_at(1:6, as.POSIXct) %>% 
  mutate(want = ifelse(pmin(col1, col2, col3, col4, col5, na.rm = T) < col6, 1L, 0L))

# A tibble: 7 x 5
  col3                col4                col5                col6                 want
  <dttm>              <dttm>              <dttm>              <dttm>              <int>
1 2000-01-09 00:00:00 2000-01-10 00:00:00 2000-01-08 00:00:00 2000-01-06 00:00:00     0
2 2000-01-05 00:00:00 2000-01-05 00:00:00 2000-01-05 00:00:00 2000-01-07 00:00:00     1
3 NA                  NA                  NA                  2000-01-05 00:00:00     1
4 NA                  2000-01-07 00:00:00 NA                  2000-01-06 00:00:00     0
5 NA                  2000-01-08 00:00:00 NA                  2000-01-08 00:00:00     0
6 NA                  NA                  NA                  2000-01-09 00:00:00     1
7 NA                  NA                  NA                  2000-01-08 00:00:00    NA
```

* Note that I didn't print out the first two columns because they didn't fit in my console.

Comment: I think this works but I have hundreds of columns so it would be a little tedious to type out col1 col 2..... col 100